# Modal Arrays and for loops

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm trying to write some Javascript for a Drupal site we run. Ideally this would run on all the pages whenever the DOM class is used.  This is what I have so far:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    
// Get the modal
    var modal = ["m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5"];
    for (var i = 0; i < modal.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(modal[i]);
    } 
      
    
// Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = ["btn1", "btn2", "btn3", "btn4", "btn5", "btn6"]; 
      for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(btn[i]);
    }

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
  
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++)
{
btn[i].onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "block";
}
}

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a id="myBtn">Open Me</a>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content drive">
    <span class="close">x</span>
    <h2>Foo</h2>

<p>Random Info</p>

<p><a class="btn" href="/bar">Foo Bar</a></p>
  </div>
```

As of now I'm getting a syntax error on this Loop

```
for (i = 0, i < btn.length; i++) <----This parenthesis
{
btn[i].onclick = function() 
modal[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Thanks for the help!
Edited: Fixed the broken JS, however, no modals will pop up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare the variable in the scope of for loop:

```
for (i = 0, i < btn.length; i++)
```

And the next line, function is wrong, need mulstache:

```
btn[i].onclick = function()
```

The correct:

```
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++)
{
    btn[i].onclick = function(){ 
        modal[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup I'm dumb, I fixed those.  However, I can't get the <a> tags to open the modal.  Should I switch to GetElementByTagName since the variable is an ID used on <a> tags?

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to do

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original post. I'm trying to create modals. Windows that appear when a link or picture is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This should have been a comment, but my comments are off, so I had to answer.
find this comment line:

```
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
```

Right below that comment, your for loop is like this:

```
for (var i = 0, i < btn.length; i++)
```

which should be :

```
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++)
```

You just missed a semicolon `;` after `var i = 0` and added a comma `,` instead.

Read the error message carefully, that was a syntax error on line 77 of the mentioned file `http://stacksnippets.net/js`